# Passing XPATH result from controller to view codeigniter

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, xpath

i have an controller that i want to use for reading from xml file.
and im using xpath for parsing the xml.

ok lets talk about code.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('index');
    $xml = simplexml_load_file(base_url('JBPLNB0056.xml'));
    echo "<strong>Test</strong><br />";
    $data['mac'] = $xml->xpath("//COMPUTER/SubNodes/NETWORK/SubNode/Property[Entry='MAC Address']/Description");
    $this->load->view('view_name', $data);
}
```

i was using `print_r($mac)` or `var_dump($mac)` in the view files and its says.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: mac

Filename: views/index.php

Line Number: 24
```

whats wrong?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you call index view, you don't pass any data,

```
$this->load->view('index');
```

what results in the error

Comment: what have you changed? write, for example, `$this->load->view('index'), array('mac'=>'');`